# I can't use \definecolor correctly

Tags: color

Please, I'd like to use this color `\definecolor{ior}{RGB}{​1,176,202}` in LaTeX.

How can I do this?

In my LaTeX, I got an error with this.

Comment: There's an invisible character of sorts right before the `1,`, try deleting `{1,` and retyping.

Comment: Please show exactly the error that you got.

Comment: You have `U+200b ZERO WIDTH SPACE  ` in  the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was one of typographical error.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. is right....

Answer (score 3):

@TorbjornT is correct: the following code compiles fine, although the color is fugly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{ior}{RGB}{1,176,202}


\begin{document}
\textcolor{ior}{hi}
\end{document}
```